# Cannot find symbol when referencing d.ts file

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to use Backbone.js with my Typescript code. When I add the import `tsc` fails to compile my code with `child.ts(12,8): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Animal'.`.

Here's the `main.ts` file:

```
export module A.B {
    export class Animal {

        constructor(argument) {
            // code...
        }

        go() : string {
            return 'snow';
        }
    }
}
```

And here's the `child.ts` file referencing it:

```
/// <reference path="main.ts" />
/// <reference path="jquery.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="underscore.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="backbone.d.ts" />

import Backbone = require("backbone");

module A.B {
    class Snake {

        constructor(argument) {
            new Animal(argument).go();
        }
    }
}
```

If I remove the import `child.ts` compiles fine. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I ended up solving it:

```
module AA.BB {
    export class Animal {

        constructor(argument) {
            // code...
        }

        go() : string {
            return 'snow';
        }
    }   
}
```

And:

```
/// <reference path="Animal.ts" />
/// <reference path="../../../keyword-exploration/public/typescript/definitions/jquery.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="../../../keyword-exploration/public/typescript/definitions/underscore.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="../../../keyword-exploration/public/typescript/definitions/backbone.d.ts" />

module AA.BB {
    class Snake extends Backbone.View<Backbone.Model> {

        constructor(argument) {
            super(argument);
            new AA.BB.Animal({});

        }
    }   
}
```

Note that there's no need for a `require` statement for Backbone.js.

Answer (score 3):

You are mixing internal and external modules. This creates a problem because the `module A.B` in your app.ts file is not in the "same common root" as the `module A.B` in your main.ts file.

## Mixed Mode

Not really recommended... and you can't supplement the internal module from within an external module...

main.ts (internal module)

```
module A.B {
    export class Animal {

        constructor(argument) {
            // code...
        }

        go(): string {
            return 'snow';
        }
    }
}
```

app.ts (external - wrapped within a `define` function)

```
/// <reference path="main.ts" />
/// <reference path="scripts/typings/backbone/backbone.d.ts" />

import Backbone = require("backbone");

module X {
    class Snake {

        constructor(argument) {
            new A.B.Animal(argument).go();
        }
    }
}
```

## Internal Modules

You can't use import statements, so you'd have to load the modules yourself (i.e. in `script` tags).

main.ts (note, we don't `export` the module)

```
module A.B {
    export class Animal {

        constructor(argument) {
            // code...
        }

        go(): string {
            return 'snow';
        }
    }
}
```

app.ts

```
/// <reference path="main.ts" />

module A.B {
    class Snake {
        constructor(argument) {
            new Animal(argument).go();
        }
    }
}
```

## Go External Modules!

You can use module loading - on your own code too. Everything is kept out of the global scope.

main.ts

```
export class Animal {

    constructor(argument) {
        // code...
    }

    go(): string {
        return 'snow';
    }
}
```

app.ts

```
import Main = require("main");

class Snake {

    constructor(argument) {
        new Main.Animal(argument).go();
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried the internal modules code you provided, but that still didn't work. As soon as I add the Backbone.js import it fails with the same message. The reason I'm using modules is to provide namespacing, so I don't want to use bare classes.

Comment: So if I wanted both the Animal class and the Snake class to be within module A.B how would I go about naming the files?

Comment: With external modules, the file represents the module - so the bare classes are not added to the global scope. The mix of internal and external modules in your case is a problem (you would need to make both modules internal and your second is wrapped within the `define` function at runtime, which means it is in a different root.

Comment: So I don't understand. How would I make both Animal and Snake be under the A.B namespace while adding the Backbone.js import?

Comment: When using external modules, you would have to add them to the same file. I would look past trying to get them in exactly the same namespace in your case though.